# How can I use batch to output a block of text using variables read in from a txt file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

TIA for any help or advice.

I have a requirement to import over 10k connection strings into MTPuTTY and the only way to do so is via the import function using an xml.

I have a connectionstrings.txt which has a list of all the strings and I'll be using each value as an entry several times in each block of text.

So the strings.txt file would look like;

username1@servername1 
username1@servername2
username2@servername1
username2@servername2
etc

The batch file should take each of these as a variable and enter them into the block before outputting the block to an xml.

The standard block should look like this;

```
<Node Type="1">
            <SavedSession>username1@servername1 <SavedSession>
            <DisplayName>username1@servername1 </DisplayName>
            <ServerName>username1@servername1 </ServerName>
            <PuttyConType>0</PuttyConType>
            <Port>22</Port>
            <UserName></UserName>
            <Password></Password>
            <PasswordDelay>0</PasswordDelay>
            <CLParams>-load username1@servername1  "username1@servername1 " -P 22</CLParams>
            <ScriptDelay>0</ScriptDelay> )
```

So far I've tried to compile an IF statement using %%I as the variable and building the block with that but I get various errors such as Echo not expected. I assume I'm being daft and missing basic syntax.

```
FOR /F %%i in (connection strings.txt) echo ( 

 <Node Type="1">
            <SavedSession>%%i</SavedSession>
            <DisplayName>%%i</DisplayName>
            <ServerName>%%i</ServerName>
            <PuttyConType>0</PuttyConType>
            <Port>22</Port>
            <UserName></UserName>
            <Password></Password>
            <PasswordDelay>0</PasswordDelay>
            <CLParams>-load %%i "%%i" -P 22</CLParams>
            <ScriptDelay>0</ScriptDelay> ) >> connection strings.xml
```

Ideally, it'd be great if the batch could generate separate XML files per user if that's possible?

Comment: Due to the syntax rules for XML, you should not consider batch-files for this task unless they in turn leverage another language or utility which understands the syntax and uses appropriate encoding. I would strongly advise that you focus your attention on PowerShell, searching and writing your code using it. This site helps you to fix a specific issue with your provided code, your code is invalid, with several issues, requiring it to be effectively rewritten, and is therefore currently off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the correct application of For loop and escaping of redirection characters.

```
@ECHO OFF
Call :find "connection strings.txt"
ECHO completed
pause
exit

:find

For /F "USEBACKQ delims=" %%a in ("%~1") DO (
    For %%i in (%%~a) DO (
    CALL :create "%%~i"
    )
) 2>nul
GOTO :EOF


:create
(
ECHO ^<Node Type="1"^>
ECHO ^<SavedSession^>%~1^</SavedSession^>
ECHO ^<DisplayName^>%~1^</DisplayName^>
ECHO ^<ServerName^>%~1^</ServerName^>
ECHO ^<PuttyConType^>0^</PuttyConType^>
ECHO ^<Port^>22^</Port^>
ECHO ^<UserName^>^</UserName^>
ECHO ^<Password^>^</Password^>
ECHO ^<PasswordDelay^>0^</PasswordDelay^>
ECHO ^<CLParams^>-load %~1 "%~1" -P 22^</CLParams^>
ECHO ^<ScriptDelay^>0^</ScriptDelay^>
)>>%~1.xml

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: The entire xml block can be written in one hit by enclosing the Echo of each line within Parenthesis. You were missing the DO element of the For command, as well as the Nested for loop to process each string delimeted by spaces. The escaping of redirection characters is the last piece you were missing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assist and description! Silly mistakes but I hadn't even considered escaping the redirect chars.

Comment: NP, hopefully you've learned a little more about batch with the assist.